# Continuous distribution and probability in specific point

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The key difference between between discrete and  continuous variable (or distribution) is that continuous variables cannot be counted. So, if I have time interval from 0 to 1 seconds, in between there are milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds etc. It never ends, so I cannot count all the values. Further, we say that probability in one specific point of continuous distribution is 0, for example, P(X=0.25) = 0. What confuses me is that if I could not count all possible values in the continuous distribution, how can I define specific point (e.g., X=0.25)? In other words, if I can say something about specific point, then I can count all specific points. But we just said that I cannot. How to resolve this paradox?

Thanks

Comment: What this has to do with probability? You can just take the reals by themselves: you can't count them, but you can talk about a specific one, like 0.25

Comment: OK. I am sorry for my ignorance. Not in probability. But how can you can talk about them when you cannot count them?

Comment: There is no paradox. Points on a continuum have zero length, so $P(X=x)=0$ under continuous distributions. Just like lines have zero area in the plane, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the set of real numbers is uncountable and so, your claim that "if I can say something about specific point, then I can count all specific points" is not correct. Indeed, you can claim that $P(x)=0$ for any $x$ in your continuous range of points, but you cannot count all such points.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what does it mean? For  example, X=0.25, means that it is X=0.25000000000000000000000000000000 till infinity? My confusion is that if the reason that I cannot count is because the number can be subdivided further and further, then how can I be sure that 0.25 cannot be subdivided further?

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean that you can't count them? You can select one specific point. Then you can select another. And another. And another. So, if I understand correctly, you say you can keep doing that until you get through them all.

But here's the catch: even if you go on for infinity, you'll never go through them all. You'll have specified infinity different numbers. But that'll be an incredibly small part of all real numbers: even if you repeat that procedure infinitely many times, you'll not make any real progress.

That said, you can specify numbers by properties. For example, "the positive one that, if multiplied by itself, gives 7" is $\sqrt{7}$. You can infinitely subdivide ranges of numbers, but the number $\sqrt{7}$ is just one.

Comment: OK. So, the idea that I *can* count them, but I *cannot* count them all. So I *can* single out a specific point, but because there are infinity many probability of each one of them is zero. Correct?

Comment: Seems right. Note that, typically when people say count them, they mean to count them all.